# Maximum degree of curves with exact rendering?

Tags: pst-func, bezier

Are cubic curves (cubic Bézier curves to be more exact) the maximum degree that one can output without conversion to straight lines?

I was looking at the [documentation](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf) for the `pst-func` package and got interested about its capability of rendering polynomial functions of any degree, since I need to render 4th degree and 5th degree polynomials. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume cubic curves is the highest degree polynomials one can output exactly (without approximations) in either PostScript or PDF, so I suppose that `pst-func` is converting polynomials to either straight lines or cubic curves.

But I couldn't find the details of the output... what accuracy do you get? Is it output as straight lines or as cubic curves? If it's the later, what algorithm is used for approximating higher degree curves with cubic Bézier curves?

Comment: IIRC, tikz uses quadratic splines.  A spline is continues up to the n-1 derivative, and discontinuous in the nth derivative at the junctions.

Comment: `ps-plot` by defaults uses `plotstyle=line`, but you can choose `plotstyle=curve`, `ecurve`, `ccurve`, `cspline` (this is cubic splines).